# Bar as pile of squares in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to obtain a bar plot where each bar is made of a pile of squares, so that it is easier to count the observations on each bar.  Here is a minimal example

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(p = rbinom(20,10,.3))   
d %>% ggplot(aes(x=p))+geom_bar(fill="white",color="black",position="stack",alpha=.5)+
      theme_void()
```

Which gives something like:

[image]

Basically, I'd like to have horizontal separating lines at every unit on the bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach can be useful:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
d = data.frame(p = rbinom(20,10,.3))   
#Plot
d %>%  
  group_by(p) %>%
  mutate(col=row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=p,fill=factor(col)))+
  geom_bar(position="stack",alpha=.5,color='black')+
  theme_void()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep('white',5))+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great. However, depending on the values randomly generated, the groups, and therefore the colors in `scale_fill_manual`, could be more than 5. I'd put a higher number.

Comment: @Massimo2013 Yes, you are right. Hoping this answer helped you :)

Comment: It did. As a further improvement, do you know if it is possible to place a number (corresponding to `col`, i.e. the row number) at the center of each square?

Comment: @Massimo2013 Yeah possible, add `geom_text(aes(label=col,y=col),vjust=3)` using the `+` in the previous line. It would work!